# calculating the average of intervals given in a column entry in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in which I have depth intervals in some cells:

The column looks like this

```
    depth
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   0_1
4   1_2
```

I want to know if there is a code I can use to find the average of the cells that are intervals in Pandas. The dataframe is very big and it would not be a smart move to do it manually.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Split the `depth` column using `Series.str.split` and create a new dataframe from this splitted column with `dtype=float` and take `mean` along `axis=1`:

```
df['depth'] = pd.DataFrame([*df['depth'].str.split('_')], dtype='float').mean(1)
```

#### Method 2:

Expand the column using `Series.str.split` with optional parameter `expand=True` and take `mean` along `axis=1`:

```
df['depth'] =  df['depth'].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(float).mean(1)
```

#### Method 3:

Lopping over every element in `depth` inside list comprehension and taking the `mean`:

```
df['depth'] = [np.array(s.split('_'), dtype='float').mean() for s in df['depth']]
```

---

```
print(df)
   depth
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.5
4    1.5
```

---

#### Timings:

```
df.shape
(50000, 1)

%%timeit @Method1
_ = pd.DataFrame([*df['depth'].str.split('_')], dtype='float').mean(1)
55 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
   
%%timeit @Method2
_  =  df['depth'].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(float).mean(1)
101 ms ± 824 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit @Method3
_ = [np.array(s.split('_'), dtype='float').mean() for s in df['depth']]
690 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. much appreciated. method 2 works perfectly. method 1 for some reason does not calculate the mean correctly. overall that was a great help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cast as a string with `.astype(str)` and then use `split('_')` with `lambda`. Then, do another lamba and use `np.mean()` with list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [0, 1, 2, '0_1', '1_2']})
df['depth'] = (df['depth'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split('_'))
                                      .apply(lambda x: np.mean([int(y) for y in x])))
df
Out[1]: 
   depth
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.5
4    1.5
```